# Will a hardware keylogger work if it is not plugged into a computer?

Tags: keyboard, keylogger

I want to use a keyboard for getting thoughts down without the distraction of a computer.  Can I plug it directly into a hardware keylogger, or would the keylogger or keyboard need phantom power from the computer?  I understand that I will not be able to see what I type, and that backspaces will be recorded as characters.  If some keyloggers could do this but not others, what is an affordable one that could do this?  Obviously, unlike the intended audience, I don't care about using it covertly.

Comment: Can't you plug a keyboard into a raspberry pi or something?

Comment: If its not plugged in, how will it receive any data, in order to log it.  Your question is not clear, because if the keylolgger is not plugged it, or enabled, then logically nothing is logged.  *It also entirely depends on the keylogger hardware itself.*

Comment: @Ramhoud I'm talking about the kind of keylogger that goes between the keyboard and the computer, not the kind that plugs into the computer separately.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @grawity I'm hoping that a keylogger will be cheaper than a raspberry pi, because it only has this one function instead of being a whole computer.

Comment: While "cheap" is subjective, raspberry pi's are considered some of the most powerful, versatile and affordable gadgets for small projects like this. Regardless, you will need a power source. Your question is likely getting down voted due to a lack of clarity and the mention of a malicious device (regardless of intention).

Comment: @root Right, I doubt many keyloggers will plug into the wall, because that would be too blatant for the intended purpose.  They probably get phantom power from the computer.  Would it work to plug a USB keylogger into an adapter that goes into the wall (the kind used for charging phones)?

Comment: @root I will look into raspberry pi's

Comment: "I want to use a keyboard for getting thoughts down without the distraction of a computer."  Sounds like you want one of those ancient devices called "a typewriter".

Answer (score 2):

Keyloggers normally need power in order to store data. More importantly, the keyboard itself needs power to actually send any signals down the wire, and for that reason there's no reason that keyloggers would include any sort of internal power supply – they're going to be connected to a PC anyway.

There's a small chance that a USB-based keyboard might work off one of those portable batteries ("power bricks") made for charging a cellphone, but more likely it will give up after being unable to do the USB handshakes.

Meanwhile, for PS/2 keyboards, crafting some custom electronics to power up the keyboard might be *much* easier. But at that point, it might also be easier to get a Pi or Beaglebone for $30.